# Accurate line ends with matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Line ends not coinciding]

The picture shows some graphs plotted on top of each other.
The thin ones have 4 data points using the style:

```
plot(xdata,ydata),'|-',lw=1.5,markersize=10)
```

and the thick, shorter ones spanning only a subset of the data points using:

```
plot(xdata[-2:-1],ydata[-2:-1],'-',lw=4.5)
```

The thick lines are however overshooting at their ends.  How can I make them end right at the data points and coincide with the markers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is because the default cap style on lines is "projecting", while you need it to be "butt". If so, something like this should help:

```
overlapped = plot(xdata[-2:-1],ydata[-2:-1],'-',lw=4.5)

for item in overlapped:
    item.set_solid_capstyle('butt')
```